# MonoTouch: consecutive views

Tags: ios, multithreading, xamarin.ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm currently trying to display the email view (`MFMailComposeViewController`) after the SMS one (`MFMessageComposeViewController`), after the user send the message or cancel..

The `MFMessageComposeViewController` is closed correctly, but the `MFMailComposeViewController` doesn't shows up.

I searched on threads, `InvokeInMainThread`, but it doesn't show or it is not in main thread.
Honestly, I don't know at all threading, and documentation I read is not clear.

Method to display `MFMessageComposeViewController`:

```
private void SendSms ()
{
    string strMessage = MessageComposer.GetMessage(isEmergency, latitude, longitude, location);
    MFMessageComposeViewController message = Sender.SendSms(strMessage, AppDelegate.contacts);
        message.Finished += delegate {
        message.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
    };
    this.NavigationController.PresentModalViewController (message, true);
}
```

The `MFMailComposeViewController` one is not very different.
I call this method that way: `InvokeOnMainThread(delegate { SendSms(); });` and works perfectly.

My bad is when this closed.
I tried `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(new Object(), SendEmail));` but it's not in the main thread.

I tried that one:

```
SendDelegate d = new SendDelegate(SendSms);
AsyncCallback callBack = new AsyncCallback(SendEmail);
IAsyncResult ar = d.BeginInvoke(new Object(), callBack, null);
```

Not in the main thread.

### Edit: solution code

Here is how it was solved ! I should have thought about that...

```
MFMessageComposeViewController message = new MFMessageComposeViewController();
message.Finished += delegate {
    message.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((e) => {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        InvokeOnMainThread (delegate { 
                SendEmail(); 
                        });
                });
    };
    this.NavigationController.PresentModalViewController (message, true);
}
```

Comment: Help us help you. IOW show us the code you're using so we can see what could be wrong and/or suggest alternatives.

Comment: Here it is. I should have done that at first. :-/ Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a second call to `PresentModalViewController` while another call to `DismissModalViewController` is in progress.  (There is probably an error presented to the console if you try to do so.)

So your options are:

- Use a timer to show the second modal view controller
- Use a different approach to your UI that makes more sense

I would recommend the second option.  Maybe use two different buttons or menu options for the two operations.

Comment: No error is presented, the second view doesn't show up. That's all.

Comment: Great ! I tried the timer and this works great. Thanks a lot !